# Prove that $\lvert f(2x) - f(x) \rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfies $f^\prime(x) = \sin(x^2 + f(x)^2)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\lvert f(2x) - f(x) \rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Honestly, I have no idea how to start this exercise... Can someone give me a hint of what theorem or idea to first think about to help me get started?

Comment: Note that $-1\le f'(x)\le 1$ for all $x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, $$|f(2x)-f(x)| \le |x|\sup_{t \in [x,2x]} |f'(t)| \le |x|$$

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of variety: We integrate both sides of the equality and use the fundamental theorem of calculus. Note that we can see $f'$ is integrable, since it is a composition of continuous functions, including $f$ itself and is thus continuous. We will integrate over closed intervals. Furthermore, the FTC applies.

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $x\geq 0$, then
$$
|f(2x)-f(x)|=\left| \int_x^{2x}f'(t)\;\mathrm dt\right|\stackrel{\text{triangle ineq.}}\leq
\int_x^{2x}|f'(t)|\;\mathrm dt\\
\leq\int_x^{2x}\mathrm dt=x
$$
if $x<0$, then we have
$$
|f(2x)-f(x)|=\left| \int_x^{2x}f'(t)\;\mathrm dt\right|=\left| \int_{2x}^{x}f'(t)\;\mathrm dt\right|\\\stackrel{\text{triangle ineq.}}\leq
\int_{2x}^x|f'(t)|\;\mathrm dt\\
\leq\int_{2x}^x\mathrm dt=-x
$$
and the inequality follows.